# Chrome DevTools Workspace and Meteor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use Chrome DevTools for some of my development for my Meteor project (specifically my LESS files, but that's irrelevant).

It looks like Chrome currently has a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277885) that causes it to use the query string for the URL for the mapping, without any ability to tell it to just ignore the question. Meteor puts query strings on all of the style sheets, JavaScript files, etc., so that's problematic.

I see two possible solutions to this. Can anyone tell me:

- Is it possible to remove the query strings from Meteor (at least in a dev environment)?
- Or, is it possible to wildcard the query strings in Chrome some way that isn't mentioned in that bug?

Or, can anyone think of another method?

**Update:** I'm not exactly sure what I did, but it loaded without the query strings once and **I was then able to** do the mapping. Chrome complained about a slight mismatch in URL but otherwise seems to be working. Does anyone know if this is going to last, or if I just got temporarily lucky?

Comment: Can you please post some code?  My meteor apps don't use query strings, so it's hard to know what you're asking...

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/42313622/10245